# indirect measurement triangle

Tags: trigonometry

A person positions a 8ft vertical pole so that the top of the pole and the top of a distant tree are aligned in the person's line of sight. The person's eye level is 5.7 ft above the ground, the distance between the person and the pole is 16ft, and the distance between the surveyor and the tree is 200 ft. How tall is the tree (y)?

[image: triangle from description]

$$\frac{x}{16} = \frac{5.7}{8}$$

$$ x = 11.4$$

how do I find y ?

The correct final answer for y is 34ft (from the book), but I don't know how to get it

Comment: You have a mistake, it has to be $\frac{x+16}{x} = \frac{8}{5.7}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find $x$. You need to take ratios of corresponding sides of triangles. So $\dfrac{x}{?} = \dfrac{5.7}{8}$. The $x$ and the 5.7 obviously come from the smallest triangle. The next triangle has sides $x+16$ and $8$. So it should be $\dfrac{x}{x+16} = \dfrac{5.7}{8}$.

For getting $y$, you need to use the smallest and largest triangle. So you get $\dfrac{x}{x+200} = \dfrac{5.7}{y}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way to find the answer without constructing of the triangle and considering unknown $x$.

Consider moving the pole from the tree to the observer changing its height at the same time so that its top is always aligned with the tree in the sight. Then, once next to the tree, the pole's height should be equal to the height of the tree, and then gradually (and linearly) be decreased to the person's height while it is being moved towards him. The height of the pole is always the weighted sum of the heights of the tree and the person with weights being distance from the pole to the tree and to the observer: $$8 = \frac{184}{200}*5.7 + \frac{16}{200}*y$$ So that $y=34.45$.

If you want to prove (to someone, or to yourself) that the height of the pole is indeed the weighted some, consider the three areas of the right trapezoids (the big one: tree person, the left one: tree pole, the right one: pole person), and see that the area of the big trapezoid = (tree height + person height) * 200/2 equals the sum of the two other trapezoids. This gives you the weighted sum.

Comment: Interesting solution.

Answer (score 1):

The height scales with base line length I.e the ratio of x to 5.7ft is the same as the ratio of (200+16+x) and the height y. More explicitly 
$$
\frac{5.7}{11.4} = \frac{y}{200} = \frac{y}{200}
$$

Comment: but wouldn't it be 200+x since, the 16ft is already inside the 200 ft.? from the pole and the tree is 184ft. The correct final answer for y is 34ft (from the book)

Comment: @hit cheers didn't look at the question just the diagram

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{y-5.7}{200}=\frac{8-5.7}{16}$

Ergo, $34.45 ft$.